# tkzDrawTangentLine ! FP error: UPN stack is empty!. \FP@errmessage #1->\errmessage {FP error: #1!}

Tags: tikz-pgf, fp, tkz-fct

The following code typesets with error `! FP error: UPN stack is empty!. \FP@errmessage #1->\errmessage {FP error: #1!}`

Anyone know how I can fix this?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

%
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{tan style/.style={-}}
\tkzInit[xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=2]
\tkzAxeXY
\tkzGrid[sub,subxstep=0.25,subystep=0.25]
\tkzFct[thick,domain=0:1]{-(\x**2)+\x+1}
\tkzDrawTangentLine[draw=true,kl=0,kr=0.5](0)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the minus sign an operation, rather than a negative, in the `\tkzFct`.  You could do that as `{0-(\x**2)+\x+1}` or, as in my MWE, `{1-(\x**2)+\x}`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

%
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{tan style/.style={-}}
\tkzInit[xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=2]
\tkzAxeXY
\tkzGrid[sub,subxstep=0.25,subystep=0.25]
\tkzFct[thick,domain=0:1]{1-(\x**2)+\x}
\tkzDrawTangentLine[draw=true,kl=0,kr=0.5](0)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]